# How to use fizzler external lib under Monodevelop

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I got a compile error using Fizzler lib (http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/) in Monodevelop IDE under Ubuntu 10.
I added .Net Assembly References and autocompletion works file, but error during the compilation occurred.

Code here:

```
    using System;
    using Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack;
    using HtmlAgilityPack;
    using System.Collections.Generic;


    namespace test
    {
        class MainClass
        {
            public static void Main (string[] args)
            {           
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                html.LoadHtml(@"some html");
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode document = html.DocumentNode;

                document.QuerySelector("a");

            }
        }
    }
```

Error CS1061: Type `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' does not contain a definition for`QuerySelector' and no extension method `QuerySelector' of type`HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (test)

Answer (score 0):

Are your HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode has that definition provided? Check again the API documentation. Please the error is clear by itself.

Comment: Yes, it has a QuerySelector method according the documentation and under WIN7 in MS Visual Studio 2010 this code works fine. I think that is a mono problem. But I did't solve yet

Comment: Do monodevelop has some thing called object browser just like in VS? Just check if this method is visible there.

Answer (score 0):

You may have found the answer to this question by now but I will post one anyway, since  people may come across this page while looking for an answer.

Replace:

```
using Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack;
```

with:

```
using myFizzler= Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeSelection;
```

and call it like this in your project:

```
HtmlNode h2 = myFizzler.QuerySelector(document, "#fbTimelineHeadline h2");
```

I hope this helps.